# USB Flash Drive Corrupted While Copying File (can't format)

Tags: hard-drive, usb, usb-flash-drive, file-corruption

I have a Kingston DT50/16GB USB stick that had been corrupted a couple of times where formatting would fix it. However this time, while copying a file, the USB got corrupted and wouldn't allow me to format it. Basically, the USB is unresponsive whenever I copy, delete, open, or create a file.

The drive is like this when plugged in:

[image: screenshot]

The directories and subdirectories are accessible:

[image: screenshot]

But when I delete or open a file, the USB becomes inaccessible and plugging it off and connecting it again gets it to the previous state:

[image: screenshot]

This is the first time I have experienced this kind of behaviour from a USB. Formatting, disk checking, creating/removing partition, gets it to the inaccessible state. Have tried multiple formatting tools, including low level ones, even tried to flash the firmware but I wasn't able to find the correct program for that. So my question is, how do I get my USB to work again? This is what I was able to find out about my corrupted USB using some tools:

FLASH VENDOR: Kington 
MODEL: DT50
VID: 0951 
PID: 1666 
CHIP VENDOR: Phison 
MEMORY CHIP: HVKJOFC 
MEMORY SIZE: 16

Any help regarding this would truly be helpful!

P.S: Data recovery tools work just fine, if that contributes.

Comment: The USB stick has failed. I just replace these.

Comment: @John Replacement is not a problem, but fixing it is. I would buy another USB either way, but at least trying to fix it and knowing USB's like these can (or cannot) be fixed is my main objective now. P.S: Have you ever encountered such a case? If so, were you ever able to succeed? And how can you tell if the USB has failed or not? Data recovery tools seem to work, they work even with the file that got the USB corrupted.

Comment: @PakistaniIbtihaj data recovery tools *read*. NAND has finite number of program/erase cycles, writing is what wears them out. Firmware can go to read-only once max P/E cycles is reached or problems are detected. OS access does even when reading does not imply nothing gets written to the drive (see: https://youtu.be/mW7eGh8P24M).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's permanently broken.**

Flash drive's controller is now in read-only mode. Opening files probably doesn't work because it's trying to bump the modification date, which requires writing to flash. Recovery tools work because they use raw disk access and don't write anything.

This kind of failure is very common. It's caused by flash memory failure. Controller manufacturer's tools could maybe reset it into normal mode, but the flash has failed anyway, so it's a matter of time until controller realizes that it's not reliable and switches into read-only mode again.

Answer (score 0):

After various researches on different sites (including the Russian ones), I found out that such a device like mine is brick and cannot be fixed (unless it allows you to write to it). In this case, you should not waste your time using utilities, checking for errors, creating partitions, or formatting. Only thing you can do is recover some of your data using a data recovery software. Your USB stick otherwise is junk.

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answer.